# events.js:174 Error: write EPIPE at ChildProcess.target._send when running jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs

node -v
v10.19.0

.\node_modules.bin\jest -v
26.0.1

CPU is intel Xeon 16 cores/32 threads and 32GB memeory

when I run `jest --coverage`, I always got failure like

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at ChildProcess.target._send (internal/child_process.js:762:20)
    at ChildProcess.target.send (internal/child_process.js:634:19)
    at ChildProcessWorker.send (C:\src\mytest\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\ChildProcessWorker.js:291:17)
    at WorkerPool.send (C:\src\mytest\node_modules\jest-worker\build\WorkerPool.js:32:34)
    at Farm._process (C:\src\mytest\node_modules\jest-worker\build\Farm.js:129:10)
    at Farm._enqueue (C:\src\mytest\node_modules\jest-worker\build\Farm.js:152:10)
    at Farm._push (C:\src\mytest\node_modules\jest-worker\build\Farm.js:159:12)
    at Promise (C:\src\mytest\node_modules\jest-worker\build\Farm.js:90:14)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Farm.doWork (C:\src\mytest\node_modules\jest-worker\build\Farm.js:56:12)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at process.nextTick (internal/child_process.js:766:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

I have tried run the command line window with administrator privilege.
add parameters such as `--maxWorkers=4`
or `set NODE_OPTIONS= --max-old-space-size=4096`

all failed with the same erors.

If I used the parameter `--runInBand`, I will get

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open ''
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at lazyFs.open (internal/fs/streams.js:115:12)
    at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: i ve had the same error code happen to me when testing my frontend and backend together, now i run backend and frontend tests seperately and this problem doesnt occur anymore. not sure if that is possible for you but maybe it helps

Answer (score 2):

This is likely an issue of [running out of memory](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10144#issuecomment-666980156). You might have a memory leak, which apparently jest's design makes [pretty easy to do](https://chanind.github.io/javascript/2019/10/12/jest-tests-memory-leak.html). That link also describes how to investigate memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried rebooting. It helped.

Try rebooting :-)